# Preserve Object State when passed into queue of functions (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, preserve

Been trying to figure out a way to preserve my object state when pushing into a function. Sample code below:

```
window.queue = window.queue || [];

var some_data = {
    "object_number":1
}

queue.push(function(){console.log("1:",some_data)});

var some_data = {
    "object_number":2
}

queue.push(function(){console.log("2:",some_data)});

// Code I Cannot Change
for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
    queue[i]();
}
```

Result of the queue execution is:

```
1: {object_number: 2}
2: {object_number: 2}
```

Can you see how when the queue is parsed (I can't change this code - it's controlled by someone else) it looks up the latest version of 'some_data'?

Any idea how to preserve the state of the object of when it was passed in? Desired result is:

```
1: {object_number: 1}
2: {object_number: 2}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following variant, which will create [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) with a local variable (`value`) each time:

```
var some_data = {
    "object_number":1
}

queue.push(((value) => () => console.log("1:",value))(some_data));

var some_data = {
    "object_number":2
}

queue.push(((value) => () => console.log("2:",value))(some_data));
```

In this case, after overwriting `some_data`, `value` does not change, since it is a separate variable. But note that changing the content of `some_data` will also change the content of `value` (then maybe you need copying of `some_data` before each `push`):

```
var some_data = {
    "object_number":1
}

queue.push(((value) => () => console.log("1:",value))(some_data));

var some_data = {
    "object_number":2
}

queue.push(((value) => () => console.log("2:",value))(some_data));

some_data.object_number = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
    queue[i]();
}

// 1: { object_number: 1 }
// 2: { object_number: 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much @z1ne2wo! I'll update accordingly and respond back with the results

Comment: Spot on @z1new2wo - I'm also posting the ES6 vs ES5 notation for other users.  

**ES6**. 
`queue.push(((value) => () => console.log("1:",value))(some_data));`.   
  
**ES5**. 
`queue.push(function (value) {
  return function () {
    return console.log("1:", value);
  };
}(some_data));`